# Javascript: Array push

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

I have this json:

```
    {"cdl":{
    "06A78000000YNmjEAG":{
    "CDocumentId":"06978000000GIzPAAW",
    "LinkedId":"a1U78000000SUtTEAW"    
    "ContentDocument":{
    "Title":"photo-1518020382113-a7e8fc38eac9"
    }
    },
    "06A78000000YNR7EAO":{    
    "CDocumentId":"06978000000GIjCAAW",
    "LinkedId":"a1U78000000SUtTEAW"    
    "ContentDocument":{    
    "Title":"photo-1517849845537-4d257902454a"
    }
    },
    "06A78000000YNPGEA4":{    
    "CDocumentId":"06978000000GIhuAAG",
    "LinkedId":"a1U78000000SUtOEAW",    
    "ContentDocument":{    
    "Title":"photo-1517519014922-8fc06b814a0e",
    }
    }
    },
    "documentos":{
    "a1U78000000SUtTEAW":{    
    "Id":"a1U78000000SUtTEAW",
    "Name":"test2"},
    "a1U78000000SUtOEAW":{    
    "Id":"a1U78000000SUtOEAW",
    "Name":"test"}
    }
    }
```

here is how i get the values:

```
var json = JSON.parse(response);
var lcList = [];
var data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < Object.values(json.documentos).length; ++i) {
         var documents = Object.values(json.documentos);
         for (var j = 0; j < Object.values(json.cdl).length; ++j) {
             var cdl = Object.values(json.cdl);
             if(cdl[j].LinkedId == documents[i].Id){
                 data.push({LinkedId : cdl[j].LinkedId, fileId : cdl[j].CDocumentId, fileName : cdl[j]["CDocument"].Title});
             }
         }
    lcList.push({nombre : documents[i].Name, data : data});
}
```

When i console.log i get this:

```
Object { nombre: "test2", data: Array
0: Object { LinkedId: "a1U78000000SUtTEAW", fileId: "06978000000GIzPAAW", fileName: "photo-1518020382113-a7e8fc38eac9" }
1: Object { LinkedId: "a1U78000000SUtTEAW", fileId: "06978000000GIjCAAW", fileName: "photo-1517849845537-4d257902454a" }
2: Object { LinkedId: "a1U78000000SUtOEAW", fileId: "06978000000GIhuAAG", fileName: "photo-1517519014922-8fc06b814a0e" }
Object { nombre: "test", data: Array
0: Object { LinkedId: "a1U78000000SUtTEAW", fileId: "06978000000GIzPAAW", fileName: "photo-1518020382113-a7e8fc38eac9" }
1: Object { LinkedId: "a1U78000000SUtTEAW", fileId: "06978000000GIjCAAW", fileName: "photo-1517849845537-4d257902454a" }
2: Object { LinkedId: "a1U78000000SUtOEAW", fileId: "06978000000GIhuAAG", fileName: "photo-1517519014922-8fc06b814a0e" }
```

What i need to get is:

```
Object { nombre: "test2", data: Array
0: Object { LinkedId: "a1U78000000SUtTEAW", fileId: "06978000000GIzPAAW", fileName: "photo-1518020382113-a7e8fc38eac9" }
1: Object { LinkedId: "a1U78000000SUtTEAW", fileId: "06978000000GIjCAAW", fileName: "photo-1517849845537-4d257902454a" }
Object { nombre: "test", data: Array​​​
2: Object { LinkedId: "a1U78000000SUtOEAW", fileId: "06978000000GIhuAAG", fileName: "photo-1517519014922-8fc06b814a0e" }
```

as you can see it should be related with LinkeId (test2 with LinkedId: "a1U78000000SUtTEAW" and test with LinkedId: "a1U78000000SUtOEAW")

Can you help me please?

Comment: Take the time to type out a sample of your input and your expected output (don't just paste console output). You also have a typo in your nested loop (`j < lengthJ ++j`)

Comment: lengthJ is a variable with the length for that loop.

Comment: What does the input look like

Comment: the json is there now! why did you downgrade the question?

Answer (score -1):

Such a weird and specific question. Lots of problems with your code so I won't even try working off of it. Here's a half-baked solution hombre

```js
const obj = {
    cdl: {
        '06A78000000YNmjEAG': {
            CDocumentId: '06978000000GIzPAAW',
            LinkedId: 'a1U78000000SUtTEAW',
            ContentDocument: {
                Title: 'photo-1518020382113-a7e8fc38eac9',
            },
        },
        '06A78000000YNR7EAO': {
            CDocumentId: '06978000000GIjCAAW',
            LinkedId: 'a1U78000000SUtTEAW',
            ContentDocument: {
                Title: 'photo-1517849845537-4d257902454a',
            },
        },
        '06A78000000YNPGEA4': {
            CDocumentId: '06978000000GIhuAAG',
            LinkedId: 'a1U78000000SUtOEAW',
            ContentDocument: {
                Title: 'photo-1517519014922-8fc06b814a0e',
            },
        },
    },
    documentos: {
        a1U78000000SUtTEAW: {
            Id: 'a1U78000000SUtTEAW',
            Name: 'test2',
        },
        a1U78000000SUtOEAW: {
            Id: 'a1U78000000SUtOEAW',
            Name: 'test',
        },
    },
};

const formatData = (data) => {
    const { documentos, cdl } = data;

    const reduced = Object.values(cdl).reduce((acc, { LinkedId, CDocumentId, ContentDocument }) => {
        const formatted = { LinkedId, fileId: CDocumentId, fileName: ContentDocument.Title };

        const curr = acc[LinkedId];

        if (curr?.Id) acc[LinkedId] = { nombre: curr.Name };

        if (!curr.data) acc[LinkedId].data = [formatted];
        else acc[LinkedId].data.push(formatted);

        return acc;
    }, documentos);

    return Object.values(reduced);
};

console.log(formatData(obj));
```